# css border only on adjacent elements

Tags: css, border

Having several divs with inline-table or inline-block display style.

According to window width the number of divs per row will change.

On higher resolution more divs will fit on each row.

Is it possible to display border only where elements touch each other?

nth selector could remove right-border on the last element, but as far as I understand not on the last element appearing on each row.

Also, is it possible to remove border-bottom only on elements that fit on the last row?

I'm not looking for a solution with a fixed number of elements by row. I'm looking for a solution that works on a layout with dynamic number of elements by row.

Comment: does this looks like what you try to do ?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jroBQw

Answer (score 0):

Try to give max-width as a percentage on each div, and write same nth style for different screen size where you see the div get wrapped, I mean media query for different resolution every time div get added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anybody, the solution used here was having a container with overflow:hidden, to hide top and left margin on elements on first row and first col.

```
.thumb { display: inline-table; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px; width: 170px; height: 170px; border: 1px solid #EEE; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px; }

<div class="col" style="padding-left:0; overflow:hidden;">
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
etc
</div>
```